# Just make a Metal frag shader a transparent color?

Tags: ios, metal

I have a simple pipeline descriptor

```
 let p = MTLRenderPipelineDescriptor()
 ...
 p.colorAttachments[0].pixelFormat = .bgra8Unorm
```

The background is plain blue

```
 let bg = MTLClearColor(red: 0, green: 0, blue: 1, alpha: 1)

 let pass = MTLRenderPassDescriptor()
 pass.colorAttachments[0].loadAction = .clear
 pass.colorAttachments[0].clearColor = bg
```

I simply draw a poly on to it, say a red one:

```
fragment half4 fattie_fragment() {
    return half4(1,0,0, 1);
}
```

Or green ...

```
fragment half4 fattie_fragment() {
    return half4(0,1,0, 1);
}
```

What to do in Metal if you want the triangle color to be transparent?

```
fragment half4 fattie_fragment() {
    return half4(0,1,0, 0.275);
}
```

(Note - TBC I don't want the overall view to be transparent. Simply the shader, the drawn triangle.)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

When you configure your render pipeline descriptor, enable blending and choose a suitable set of blend factors and operations. For example:

```
let p = MTLRenderPipelineDescriptor()
...
p.colorAttachments[0].isBlendingEnabled = true
p.colorAttachments[0].rgbBlendOperation = .add
p.colorAttachments[0].alphaBlendOperation = .add
p.colorAttachments[0].sourceAlphaBlendFactor = .sourceAlpha
p.colorAttachments[0].destinationAlphaBlendFactor = .oneMinusSourceAlpha
p.colorAttachments[0].sourceRGBBlendFactor = .sourceAlpha
p.colorAttachments[0].destinationRGBBlendFactor = .oneMinusSourceAlpha
```